# GDI+ Generic Error, multple frame tiff, multiple image formats

Tags: c#, .net, gdi+, tiff

I have seen many issues involving the GDI+ Generic Error, but I have not seen this particular matter raised before.  We are consistently getting the error, on Windows systems other than Windows 8, when attempting to read (System.Drawing.Image.SelectActiveFrame) a multiple-frame tiff that includes frames in mixed Photometric Interpretation formats.  That is to say, the file includes both RGB color and min-is-white formats, with corresponding differences in the Bits/Sample and Samples/Pixel frame parameters. The error is consistently raising as soon as a frame is encountered with a format that is different from that of the first frame.

```
            // Convert File from .tiff to .PDF
    static void ConvertFile(string file, string pdffilename)
    {
      string localMessage = string.Empty;

        try
        {
            //if it's a PDF Just renamed it and continue
            if (file.ToLower().Contains(".pdf"))
            {
                File.Copy(file, pdffilename);
                return;
            }
            // If file exists return
            if (File.Exists(pdffilename)) { return; }

            using (var stream = new FileStream(pdffilename, FileMode.Create))
            {
              localMessage = "01";
                var document = new iTextSharp.text.Document();
                localMessage = "01";
                var writer = iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, stream);
                localMessage = "02";
                var bm = Bitmap.FromFile(file);
                localMessage = "03";
                var total = bm.GetFrameCount(FrameDimension.Page);
                localMessage = "04";
                document.Open();
                //iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfContentByte cb = writer.DirectContent;
                localMessage = "05";
                iTextSharp.text.Image img = null;
                for (var currentframe = 0; currentframe < total; ++currentframe)
                {
                  localMessage = "06=>" + currentframe.ToString();
                  bm.SelectActiveFrame(FrameDimension.Page, currentframe);
                  localMessage = "07=>" + currentframe.ToString();
                  img = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(bm, ImageFormat.Bmp);
                  localMessage = "08=>" + currentframe.ToString();
                  img.ScalePercent(72f / img.DpiX * 100);
                  localMessage = "09=>" + currentframe.ToString();
                  img.SetAbsolutePosition(0, 0);
                  localMessage = "10=>" + currentframe.ToString();
                  iTextSharp.text.Rectangle pageRect = new iTextSharp.text.Rectangle(0, 0, img.ScaledWidth, img.ScaledHeight);
                  localMessage = "11=>" + currentframe.ToString();
                  document.SetPageSize(pageRect);
                  localMessage = "12=>" + currentframe.ToString();
                  document.NewPage();
                  localMessage = "13=>" + currentframe.ToString();
                  document.Add(img);
                }
                localMessage = "14";
                bm.Dispose();
                localMessage = "15";
                document.Close();

                localMessage = "16";
                stream.Close();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
          string msg = exception.Message + "\r\n" +
            "Coversion Error--\r\n" +
            "\tinput file name: " + file + "\r\n" +
            "\toutput file name: " + pdffilename + "\r\n" +
            "\tlocal message" + localMessage + "\r\n";
            Console.WriteLine(msg);
            SaveError(msg);
            throw;
        }
    }
```

The "local message" is always "06=>n", where n is the 0-based index of the frame that transitions to a new format.

Does anyone know why this is happening or how to fix it?

Comment: I have the same error every time when I switch to other page than first (index 0). Problem occurs on Windows 7.